# How to change xterm colors using .Xdefaults file?

Tags: linux, colors, xterm

I have created the following .Xdefaults file in my home directory but xterm still have default colors, what might be wrong here?

```
*xterm*background: #101010
*xterm*foreground: #d0d0d0
*xterm*cursorColor: #d0d0d0
*xterm*color0: #101010
*xterm*color1: #960050
*xterm*color2: #66aa11
*xterm*color3: #c47f2c
*xterm*color4: #30309b
*xterm*color5: #7e40a5
*xterm*color6: #3579a8
*xterm*color7: #9999aa
*xterm*color8: #303030
*xterm*color9: #ff0090
*xterm*color10: #80ff00
*xterm*color11: #ffba68
*xterm*color12: #5f5fee
*xterm*color13: #bb88dd
*xterm*color14: #4eb4fa
*xterm*color15: #d0d0d0
```

Comment: Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89347/8383 . I found that post very helpful for debugging X settings and was able to successfully get xclock to look good in "dark mode". Maybe you can apply the same techniques to xterm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Di you try `xrdb .Xdefaults` before (re-)launching xterm?

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdefaults "If you background the execution of xrdb in a chain of commands in ~/.xinitrc, the programs launched in the same chain might not be able to make use of it, so it is recommended to never background the xrdb command within ~/.xinitrc. The older (deprecated) ~/.Xdefaults file is read every time you start an X program such as xterm, but only if xrdb has not ever been used in the current X session." So maybe xrdb was already invoked somewhere (in your Xinitrc, Xresources or other file)?